# Invoke admin services in wso2 products via http instead of https?

Tags: http, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to invoke admin services in wso2 products via `http` protocol ?
How can we configure it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer.

Yes, Its possible.

Open `[Product_Home]/repository/conf/carbon.xml` file and uncomment below element.

`<HttpAdminServices>*</HttpAdminServices>`

Uncommenting above parameter would expose all AdminServices in `HTTP` transport. With `HTTP` transport your credentials and data routed in public channels are vulnerable for sniffing attacks.